# Can XTS + checksum be used for authenticated encryption?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, disk-encryption, xts, checksum

Is it possible to use XTS + a checksum for authenticated encryption?  Specifically, it seems like a good $n$ bit checksum applied before encryption should ensure that any change to the ciphertext will be detected by the plaintext checksum with a high probability ($1 - 2^{-n}$).

Comment: a) please  don't do authenticate-then-encrypt b) please don't roll your own crypto c) CTR and similar nodes have IND-CPA security reductions while XTS does not, so try to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: @SEJPM I know, but XTS is widely used for disk encryption, and I am asking if a fast checksum can detect tampering with an XTS-encrypted disc.  I _know_ any decent cryptographic hash could (almost certainly even MD5) &ndash; I am asking if (say) GHASH can

Comment: You might want to take a look at [OCB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode), it uses simple *xor* as checksum.

Comment: @CodesInChaos OCB is (1) patented and (2) cannot be used for $>2^{32}$ blocks.

Comment: OP may not be "rolling their own", but asking if a system that naturally combines the two such as a ZFS filesystem (which uses a CRC checksum to protect all data and metadata) encrypted using AES-XTS would still be malleable.

Comment: @forest that is exactly what I am wondering.